# How can you hide letters in a word with an asterisk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, words

I am currently working on a hangman project. I am having problems with hiding characters in words with asterisks - like, "word" would be `****`, then when the player makes a guess and it's correct, the letter would appear where it should be, instead of the asterisk, like if you guessed 'o', `*o**`. How can I do this?

This is my current code.

```
import random
start = 1

class hangman():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__word = word
        self.__incorrectg = none

    word = random.choice(open(input("please type the file you wish to open   ")).readlines())
    print (word)
    lettercount = len([ltr for ltr in word if ltr.isalpha()])
    print (lettercount)
```

Comment: thanks for the edit doork

Answer (score 1):

If you stored the players guesses in a list for instance:

```
used_letters = [] # and append guesses to this, both right and wrong
```

so as soon as the user inputs a `guess`, you append it to `used_letters`.

```
with open(filepath) as f: # this might be a better way to open the file
    word = random.choice(f.readlines()) # after this statement the file is auto closed, and frees up the memory
```

and you have the actual word stored as a list as in:

```
word = list(word) #made into a list of the letters in the word
```

then you could do something like:

```
guessed_string = ''.join(letter if letter in used_letters else '*' for letter in the_word)
```

**EDIT:**

```
#prints out the starred string. i.e. unguessed letters are '*' and guessed letters that appear in the word appear as normal letters.
print guessed_string
```

let me know if this works for you.

Example:

if `word = 'arbitrary'`

`word = list(word)` gives:

```
['a','r','b','i','t','r','a','r','y']
```

if the user has so far guessed:

```
used_letters = ['a', 'b', 'e', 'r']
```

then

```
guessed_string = ''.join(letter if letter in used_letters else '*' for letter in word)

print guessed_string
```

will give:

```
'arb**rar*'
```

Comment: iv taken the word froma file and it is randomly chosen from a list in tat file.

Comment: made a couple of small changes again

Comment: how would i then print after a guess has been made.l

Comment: when i want it be `***a****`] for example

Comment: ok, updated post again. And fixed some typos.. more typos! sorry, fixed now I think.

Comment: I used similar code in my own hangman game and it works perfectly

Comment: i have a problem. insteast of it returning `***a*** it just returns the used letters

Comment: can you please post the code you tried(inluding my suggestions) at the bottom of your original post so I can see what's wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
value="C9T1573518"

new_value=value[0:3]
new_value+="".join(value[l].replace(value[l],"*") for l in range(3,len(value),1))
print(
    new_value
)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/usr/bin

def password(word):

    class __password:   
        def __repr__(self):
            return "*" * len(word)

    return __password()

word = password("Mypassword123")
print word
```

Took a while but I was finally able to get it:

```
#!/usr/bin
def password(word):

    external_repr = set()

    class __password:

        def __repr__(self):
            return ''.join(word[i] if word[i] in external_repr else '*' for i in xrange(len(word)))

        def __eq__(self, somestring):
            return word == somestring

        def guess(self, letter):
            external_repr.add(letter[0])

        def encrypt(self):
            return "*" * len(word)

    return __password()

word = password("Mypassword123")

if word == "Mypassword123": print "Passwords match!"

print "The encrypted password is", word.encrypt()

word.guess('s')
print "After your guess, the word is now", word
```

Comment: could you please explain what it does?

Comment: What do you mean by show individual characters? Ok nvm, I will update the code

Comment: so if Mypassword123 was ************ and the player guessed "a", how would i update it so it shows ******a*******

Comment: That's a very interesting use of classes. But why not just do `def password(word): return "*" * len(word)`?

Comment: This is such bad practice - it's not even useful to the OP. A function encapsulating a class that's named with double underscores, which only defines a repr that refers to the enclosing function's argument? Just wow... I can't not -1 this...

Comment: @JonClements, I hope it is now clear why the class was encapsulated by a function. This is to get around python's lack of private members.